# How to open two Animator views in Unity?

Tags: unity

How can I open two Animator views in Unity editor?

What I tried so far is to lock an Animator view and go to Window=>Animator.

That did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, some Unity windows are bound to a single instance.  Animator is one of those.  So, as short as the answer is, as of at least Unity 5.6.1, you cannot have multiple Animator tabs open.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

Right click on an existing tab (Game, Scene, doesn't matter) and go to "add tab."  Add a new Animation tab. You can have as many as you'd like.  When I first read your question I was like "what, really? only one?" and did this immediately out of habit and had no trouble.  Then re-read your question.  Window -> Animation jumps to the first animation tab open, creating it if there isn't one.

[image: New tab]

However, this only works for the types listed in this menu.  For other windows (such as the Asset Store, Anima**tor**, Profiler, Sprite Packer, Services, Lighting...) you can only have *one.* There is no ability to create a second tab of that type.  For most of these (Profiler comes to mind) there's no *need* to have more than one. For the others, it might be a technical restriction (you can have two Inspector tabs, for instance, but they'd always show the same information...so I don't know why that one's supported in multiple).

Comment: FYI, that's an Animation tab, not an Animator tab.  They are wholly different things.  You can only have a single Animator tab open at a time.

Comment: @JesseWilliams Ah! You are correct. I was scanning the window list because I knew that the words were different and didn't see "Animator" at all (and I mean in the Window menu). Its one of those things I don't use at all (an artist I am not).